# CakePHP 3.4 load jQuery to layout

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I started using libraries like jQuery or Twitter Bootstrap with composer. Now I want to load the `jquery.min.js` from `/vendor/components/jquery/` into my `/src/Template/Layout/default.ctp`.

How can I do that?
Because using a normal uri doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Cake doesn't interpret the file as a file. It looks for a Controller:

```
Error: VendorController could not be found.
```

How can I load the JS-file properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is perhaps a little broad, but you probably want to look into using something like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com) or [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) to build your assets from the Composer files to your app's webroot. These will also enable you to concatenate and minimise all your JS/CSS assets to improve performance. Although personally I'd probably use a CDN to deliver a library like jQuery as it is so commonly used on the web that you can benefit from cross-site caching.

The reason why you are getting an error like "Error: VendorController could not be found." is because Cake can't find the 'vendor' directory inside 'webroot' so is looking for a Controller instead due to the way it handles magic routes (this bit in the routes.php file `$routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');`).

If you don't want to use a tool like Gulp or Webpack you could symlink the relevant files in your webroot folder, but personally I'd use my initial suggestions as these will give you many other benefits. If you do symlink just make sure you don't symlink the entire vendor directory as you don't want to expose all the code in there.

Comment: Thank you. I never worked with `Gulp` or `Webpack`. Kinda overwhelming all those new libraries. `Composer`, `Node`, etc. Well I fixed it with a symlink to my vendors folder. But I'll have a look at `Gulp`.

Comment: @MattBackslash this might help you when you come to look at Gulp: http://andy-carter.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-the-task-runner-gulp.

Answer (score 1):

You should place all your `js` in `/webroot/js` folder. You can use it inline by using:

```
echo $this->Html->script('jquery.min');
```

this would load : `<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes, usually I did it this way. For this new project I'd like to use jQuery with composer, so I can update the jQ library with composer and not searching all files online by my own. I fixed it currently with a symlink from `/webroot/js/jquery.min.js` to `/vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js`